# Package structure naming convention?

Tags: java, package, naming-conventions

Generally we structure package structure based on below convention

> we form a unique package name by first having (or belonging to an
>   organization that has) an Internet domain name, such as sun.com.  You
>   then reverse this name, component by component, to obtain, in this
>   example, com.sun, and use this as a prefix for your package names,
>   using a convention developed within your organization to further
>   administer package names.

I am working in a company abc which has website with domain abc.com. Now i am building a product
xyz which does not have any domain and website. Different clients will buy it and then get domains for themselves.
My question is should package name by convention start with `com.abc or com.xyz`

Comment: it totally depends on your choice but as per me it should be com.abc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put it in the package `com.xyz` it might collide with a product developed by another developer or vendor if he/she uses the same wrong naming convention, which would mean both of them cannot be used in the same Java application or classes from both of them cannot be imported without potential collision.

If you name it `com.abc.xyz` and if another vendor/developer develops the same product and uses the same naming convention, he/she would put it into the package `com.def.xyz` which would allow using both of them in the same Java application without having to worry about collisions.

So definately the package `com.abc.xyz` is recommended.

Answer (score 0):

This convention is just a naming convention, so it has nothing to do with the tech part and all the names you give to it will be (in a certain way) harmless. The naming convention is only used in order to structure your code and avoid collision with other  developments; that is the main reason to use the domain name. So, in the end, you can use any name you really want or feels it's right for your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the discussion whether to use the convention or not, if you use it it should reflect your companies domain and is not at all related to possible customers.

In addition to avoiding collisions it provides information about who created e.g. a library, which can help if you find a random (possibly renamed) library in a project and want to find information about it.